# Check Bluetooth Device Status

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth

Is there any method to check whether there is any Bluetooth device connected to my Ubuntu 22.04? I know that the drop-down in the top bar or Bluetooth Settings will help. I am actually trying to fetch it through a Python file or a `.sh` file and display an indicator so that I can add some notification-window like indicator. Thanks.

Edit 1:

I have this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63334566/python-how-to-get-connected-bluetooth-devices-linux) that helps a lot. I just need some method to add a dismissible indicator that reminds me that a Bluetooth device is connected. I need this to remind me to disconnect the device before turning off the computer.

```
import pydbus

bus = pydbus.SystemBus()

adapter = bus.get('org.bluez', '/org/bluez/hci0')
mngr = bus.get('org.bluez', '/')

def list_connected_devices():
    mngd_objs = mngr.GetManagedObjects()
    for path in mngd_objs:
        con_state = mngd_objs[path].get('org.bluez.Device1', {}).get('Connected', False)
        if con_state:
            addr = mngd_objs[path].get('org.bluez.Device1', {}).get('Address')
            name = mngd_objs[path].get('org.bluez.Device1', {}).get('Name')
            print(f'Device {name} [{addr}] is connected')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_connected_devices()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo service bluetooth status
```

if you entered this command you will see the status of bluetooth like this to know bluetooth connectivity

```
○ bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor pre>
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
```

or you can use application like [image]